# How to merge csv file line by line python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, merge

Hello I am new to Python and I am trying to merge these two files fileA and fileB into one using this piece of code

```
    a = pandas.read_csv(fileA)
    b = pandas.read_csv(fileB)
    b = b.dropna(axis=1)
    merged = b.merge(a, on="day")
    merged.to_csv(output, index=False)
```

But the problem is instead of it merging line by line it merges the first line of fileA with all lines of fileB! below you'll find an example

**content of fileA**

```
numb,day

one,sat
two,sun  
three,mon
```

**content of fileB**

```
day,month,color,shape

sat,apr,black,circle
sun,may,white,triangle
mon,jun,red,square
```

**expected output**

```
numb,day,month,color,shape

one,sat,apr,black,circle
two,sun,may,white,triangle
three,mon,jun,red,square
```

**what I am actually getting**

```
numb,day,month,color,shape

one,sat,apr,black,circle
one,sat,may,white,triangle
one,sat,mon,jun,red,square
two,sun,apr,black,circle
two,sun,may,white,triangle
two,sun,jun,red,square
.
.
.
```

So how can I merge the files line by line instead of all of this, or what exactly am I doing wrong here?

I am using Python 3.7

Comment: try [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) : `df_out = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Indeed,`concat` is the way to go. You used `merge`, which kinda does a JOIN under the hood, hence the undesired result.

Comment: @chrisA does concat work on csv files?

Comment: No, it’s a pandas method for concatenating   DataFrames. a and b are DataFrames after read_csv

Comment: oh I see now I thought I had to change the function I had already. and it worked thank you so much @ChrisA

Comment: could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine DataFrames:

```
a = pandas.read_csv(fileA)
b = pandas.read_csv(fileB)
b = b.dropna(axis=1)

merged = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)

merged.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join)

```
a = pandas.read_csv(fileA)
b = pandas.read_csv(fileB)
fileA.join(fileB.set_index('day'), on='day')
```